# relate pagination to entry on page

Tags: pagination

I have managed to sort most Craft CMS questions out by reading the docs and feedback on StackExchange but am having issues with this one.

I have a page with a list of entries down the right side and the main entry content to the left.

The list is paginated.  When I go to say page 2 of the pagination and click on an entry, the page reloads with the page 1 pagination list.

How can I get the page to remember that the entry belongs to page 2?

```
{% paginate craft.entries.section('orchard').limit('5').id('not ' ~ entry.id)  as entriesOnPage %}

 {% for entry in entriesOnPage %}
   {% for asset in entry.mediaThumb %}
     <div class="shuntalittle">
      <h6><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></h6>
      <a href="{{ entry.url }}">
        <img src="{{ asset.getUrl('thumbTransform') }}" alt="{{ asset.title }}">
      </a>
     </div>
   {% endfor %}    
 {% endfor %}

  <div class="pagination-centered shuntalittle">
    <ul class="pagination">
      {% if paginate.prevUrl %}
        <li><a href="{{ paginate.prevUrl }}" class="arrow">&laquo;</a></li>
      {% endif %}
      {% for page, url in paginate.getPrevUrls(5) %}
        <li><a href="{{ url }}">{{ page }}</a></li>
      {% endfor %}
      <li class="current"><a href="">{{ paginate.currentPage }}</a></li>
      {% for page, url in paginate.getNextUrls(5) %}
        <li><a href="{{ url }}">{{ page }}</a></li>
      {% endfor %}
      {% if paginate.nextUrl %}
        <li><a href="{{ paginate.nextUrl }}" class="arrow">&raquo;</a></li>
      {% endif %}
    </ul>
  </div>
{% endpaginate %}
```

Many thanks, Alex

Answer (score 1):

You would need to pass the current pagination page number with your entry links and than make Craft
respond to URLs in a format like this: example.com/my-section/p2/my-entry-slug.

I guess this is more complicated than you'd think, as this is probably not possible to do with
the default `paginate` tag and its preset routes. And I also don't know of a way to combine the `paginate`
tag's page token with custom routes.

So I believe there's no other choice left than replacing `paginate` with a custom solution replicating its
functionality.

This is possible with [dynamic routes](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/routing#dynamic-routes) and some logic in your templates. So you'd first have to set up a route
with a `[page]` and a `[slug]` token, which you can then access in your template.

`my-section/p[page]/[slug]` and
`my-section/p[page]`

I'll give some example code (untested and incomplete), to help you get started with the template.

All the pagination links build upon the route's `page` variable used in `craft.entries`'s [`offset`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#offset) and [`limit`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#limit) parameters. With custom routes you also have to query for your `entry` entry model manually, I set it up to get the page's first entry
if there's no `slug` variable set from your route.

```
{# Set params #}
{% set params = {section: 'orchard'} %}
{% set entriesPerPage = 5 %}

{% if page is defined %}
    {% set offsetParam = (page - 1) * entriesPerPage %}
    {% set pageSegment = '/p' ~ page %}
{% else %}
    {% set offsetParam = 0 %}
    {% set pageSegment = '' %}
{% endif %}

{# Get the entry model #}
{% if slug is defined %}
    {% set entry = craft.entries.slug(slug).first() %}
{% else %}
    {% set entry = craft.entries(params).offset(offsetParam).first() %}
{% endif %}

{# Get pagination params #}
{% if page is defined %}
    {% set entriesOnNextPage = craft.entries(params).offset(offsetParam + 1) %}

    {% if entriesOnNextPage|length %}
        {% set nextPageSegment = '/p' ~ page + 1 %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if page == 1 %}
        {% set prevPageSegment = '' %}
    {% else %}
        {% set prevPageSegment = '/p' ~ page - 1 %}
    {% endif %}
{% else %}
    {% set entriesOnNextPage = craft.entries(params).offset(entriesPerPage) %}

    {% if entriesOnNextPage|length %}
        {% set nextPageSegment = '/p2' %}
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}

<article>
    <h2>{{ entry.title }}</h2>
</article>

<nav>
    {% set entriesOnPage = craft.entries(params).offset(offsetParam).limit(entriesPerPage) %}

    {% for entry in entriesOnPage %}
        {% set image = entry.mediaThumb.first() %}

        <a href="/my-section{{ pageSegment }}/{{ entry.slug }}">
            <img src="{{ image.url }}">
        </a>
    {% endfor %}

    {% if prevPageSegment is defined %}
        <a href="/my-section{{ prevPageSegment }}">Previous Page</a>
    {% endif %}

    {% if nextPageSegment is defined %}
        <a href="/my-section{{ nextPageSegment }}">Next Page</a>
    {% endif %}
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much for your detailed response Carl. As I was working to implement this solution I decided to go back and take a look at url segments (I am used to ExpressionEngine).   I found that craft.request has a whole series of properties including getPageNum() which gets the pagination page number from the url.

I changed the urls link in my pagination list to:

```
<a href="{{ entry.url }}/p{{ craft.request.getPageNum() }}">
```

and that maintained the pagination position in the url which basically does what I need.

Cheers,

Alex

Comment: That's great you found this simple solution. So, Craft is able to match the route example.com/my-section/my-entry/p2 to an entry with the slug my-entry and also gets the pagination page from the URL. Too bad you can't configure it to have the URLs more hierarchically correct as in example.com/my-section/p2/my-entry.